# Sails/Bookshelf Running a script that uses the Sails/Bookshelf environment

Tags: node.js, sails.js, bookshelf.js

I would like to create a script to be run in the background of my server as a cron task.

I would like the script to have access to the sails environment (ie, loading all the modules, especially bookshelf and knex, and the database connection).

so that I could create a file myscript.js that looks something like

```
var environment = require("sails_environment")

// code that uses bookshelf etc exactly as if it were written 
// inside a controller action
```

I actually only need the bookshelf module and db connection for this script,  so it could be that bookshelf has a way to do this, but I imagine it is something built in to Sails.

Comment: This question is *all over the place*. You need to be more specific about your question is.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do what you want. Here are a few.

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2092#issuecomment-56043637

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-schedule

http://www.worldnucleus.com/2014/12/run-cron-job-in-sailsjs.html